# What is the relation between the length of period of simple continued fraction expansion of quadratic algebraic numbers and the integer

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, continued-fractions

As we know,$\sqrt{2} = [1;2,2,2,2,…]$; while $\sqrt{14}= [3;1,2,1,6,1,2,1,6…]$,let $L$ the length of period  of simple continued fraction expansion of quadratic algebraic numbers  be the number of integers  in sequence of one periods, that is  $L=i$ for   quadratic algebraic number$\sqrt{A}$,where $\sqrt{A} = [a_0;a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_i,a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_i,…]$.

We know different quadratic algebraic numbers may have different  lengths of period of simple continued fraction expansion  What is the relation between the length of period of simple continued fraction expansion of quadratic algebraic numbers and the corresponding integer $A$?It is looks like $L$ is relevent to the prime factors of $A$.Is there any formula?

Comment: The question has been posted on mathoverflow laterly,and has been given reference by Andres Caicedo ,the reference is https://andrescaicedo.wordpress.com/2011/10/10/596-continued-fractions/